# Draw more axes than default in python matplotlib 3d

Tags: python, matplotlib

I could like to have a black vertical axis in a 3D plot at {-xlim, -ylim} instead of just at {+xlim, +ylim}. Is there a way to turn this on (and not just draw an additional line there?)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)
ax.w_xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
ax.w_yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
ax.w_zaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
ax.xaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('black')
ax.yaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('black')
ax.zaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('black')

plt.show()
```

I'd like a line where the highlighting is here.
[image: I'd like a line where the highlighting is here.]